# How to replace values in a nested list based on place positions in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, replace, nested

For my research paper, I'm using python to solve an optimization problem. I followed an online course for the basics of python, but now I'm completely stuck trying to build the first part of the model.

The situation:
I have 27 possible scenarios and every sublist contains 3 periods with its own possible outcome (0,1, or 2). I wrote it in python as followed:

```
scenarios=[
[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1,2],[0,2,0],[0,2,1],[0,2,2],
[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,2],[1,1,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,0],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],
[2,0,0],[2,0,1],[2,0,2],[2,1,0],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,0],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]]
```

The numbers 0,1, and 2 represent if demand of each period is low, average, or high. The real values are listed in python like this:

```
minimum=[5,10,0]     #0  --5 in period 1, 10 in period 2, 0 in period 3
mean= [10,30,20]     #1  --10 in period 1, 30 in period 2, 20 in period 3
maximum=[15,50,40]   #2  --15 in period 1, 50 in period 2, 40 in period 3
```

Now I need to modify the list with scenarios or create a new one where the actual values are listed instead of the numbers 0,1, and 2. I have no clue how.
So I want to create a list that looks like this:

```
real=[[5,10,0],[5,10,20]....[15,50,40]]
```

The best I could come up with is this not-working version:

```
def dpt():                      #demand per time period
        for s in scenarios:
                for t in s:
                        if t[0]==0:
                         real=minimum[0]
                        elif t[0]==1:
                         real=mean[0]
                        elif t[0]==2:
                         real=maximum[0]
                        elif t[1]==0:
                         real=minimum[1]
                        elif t[1]==1:
                         real=mean[1]
                        elif t[1]==2:
                         real=maximum[1]
                        elif t[2]==0:
                         real=minimum[2]
                        elif t[2]==1:
                         real=mean[2]
                        else:              #t[2]==2
                         real=maximum[2]
                        return real
```

The first problem already with the loop is this:

```
  if t[0]==0:
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

How to solve this? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think `t` is representing the int() inside your nested lists thus you cant reference the `t[0]` of an int() - try removing the `for t in s:` loop and reference the `s` as you have the `t`

Comment: In your code, `t` is an integer, not a dictionary. So, this is why the exception happened.

Comment: Where are you calling your `dpt()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple:

```
for s in scenarios:
    s[0]= minimum[s[0]] # this will replace the value of s[0],if s[0] is 0,s[0] will be replaced of minimum[0]
    s[1]= mean[s[1]]
    s[2]= maximum[s[2]]
```

This is all, the code can even be more simple if you know more about python.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know it could be this simple.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you encounter a TypeError, the easiest way to check what's wrong is to see what is inside the variable. Try this:

```
scenarios=[
[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1,2],[0,2,0],[0,2,1],[0,2,2],
[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,2],[1,1,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,0],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],
[2,0,0],[2,0,1],[2,0,2],[2,1,0],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,0],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]]

for s in scenarios:
    for t in s:
        print t
```

Which will result in:

```
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
2
...
```

And this is the reason for the error you are getting. There is no `t[0]` as `t` is just an int.

If you need further help, try to ask more specific questions using generic terms (*demands* and *periods* can be confusing for persons not familiar with your paper).

Best regards!